# How to upload a file for an existing user in the database and create a folder for them in laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am developing a document archive system and i want the user to be able to upload a file to a specific folder that should be linked to an existing user in the database. what do i need to do?

This is for xampp server running PHP 7.0.3 and with Laravel 5.4. I am able to upload a file but it has no owner.

No code to display.

I expect to be able to search for a user according to their name and retrieve their files

Comment: I doubt if you really need to create folders. Unless the users will want to access those folders via FTP (very unlikely!)? Are you thinking of having some sort of reference between the uploaded files and the user who uploaded it? Just let the files be uploaded to a designated folder on the server (no matter who uploads it) and give every file a unique psuedo-name. Have a table with these columns: `{user_id, original_file_name, uploaded_file_path}` and store the relevant information in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use one to many relationships for this.

First create a document model and migration with below command.

```
php artisan make:model Document -m // -m option for migration file
```

Configure user and document models for one to many relation

**User Model**

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
}
```

**Document Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**create_documents_table Migration**

Edit migration file and add `name, path,type` etc.. columns..

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('documents', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string("name");
            $table->string("path");
            $table->string("type");

            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

then run `php artisan:migrate` command.

Done! So let upload a file..

```
public function upload(Request $request){

   // get file from request
   $file = $request->file("document");

   // get username for file path (if user directory doesn't exist, Storage gonna create it)
   $username = $request->user()->username;

   // make file name unique
   $file_name = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $realName = str_slug($file_name); // it makes seo frendly
   $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $newFileName = $username."/".$realName . "-" . time() . "." . $extension;

   // store document on db (make sure these columns fillable on model or it throws error)
   $request->user()->documents()->create([
        "name"=>$file_name
        "path"=>$newFileName 
        "type"=>"document"
      ]); 
   // move uploaded file
   Storage::disk("locale")->put($newFileName,file_get_contents($file));

}
```

For more further I strongly to suggest you to read [documents.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) It makes you to understand how eloquent handle with the relational queries

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what i want is to allow a user to be able to upload documents for particular students , its about digitizing old records. I want the person uploading to first enter in the student id on the interface and then the system should check if that student id exists, if it does it should upload it directly to that student. so a student can have many documents but only one document can be owned by a student.

Comment: @KayC, then you should use one to many relationship. So one student may have multiple documents. And these documents belongs to only one student. I will update update my answer for this approach

Comment: I have seen it, it doesn't solve my other problem with the user interface however. Lets say i have this upload form yes and the first text input is student id. I want the user uploading a file to enter a student id and select the file, after this when they click submit, i want the system to check the database if that id exists, if it does then the uploaded file will belong to that student, if it doesnt exist, it should return an error.

Comment: @KayC, ohh I thougt user is a student.. Then all you need to do swtich User relation with Student. That shouldnt be a problem. Also you dont have to enter student id ? How user can knows all studens ids ? it makes everythings harder. I suggest you to select certain student before uploading the document. You can use select2 or other plugins for this purpose. so user can choose document belongs to which student at the begining

Comment: how about displaying a hierachy folders in the blade view? eg a folder that belongs to that student and inside that folder, another folder and inside that folder the files belonging to it.

Comment: @KayC, well Storage facade doesn't support kind a feature but you can get that for a single file if you parse the file path. lets assume we have a student named Joe and he has a document about Math. So the file path is `"joe/math/exam.pdf"` right ? if we explode the path -> `explode("/",$path)` and remove last item (which is file name with extension) `array_pop($array)` we will able to get directory structure . then `print_r($array). But If you want to display all images within directory hierarchy you may use media libraries written for laravel

Answer (score 0):

File uploads should not be handled by folders. When you upload a file, give it a unique name. Save this name in a database files for example, where you have columns user_id, and file_name. Then when you want to get all files for a specific user you just send query to the database. Laravel already has most of this done and it looks like this:

```
$uploadedImage = $request->image->store('images');
```

This will return something like this:

```
"images/7UmX8yrOs2NYhpadt4Eacq4TFtpPGUCw6VTRJhfn.img"
```

then you do something like this:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->user_id = $user_id;
$image->path = $uploadedImage();
$image->save();
```

If you want to give the name for the image yourself you can use `storeAs` instead of `store` method like this:

```
$uploadedImage = $request->image->storeAs('images', $filename);
```